# Neo4j Cypher pattern: fail-fast on multi-part pattern

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a multi-part cypher pattern, where the first part is really fast and the subsequent parts are really slow:

```
MATCH (m:EntityX {indexed_property: 1234})-[]->(a0),
(a0:EntityY)-[]-(a1:Entity:Y),
(a1:EntityY)-[]-(a2:Entity:Y),
...
RETURN m
```

Now, I experience that queries are slow because the entire pattern is being evaluated even though most queries will to fail (produce 0 rows) a the first part of the pattern. So how can one ensure that the pattern fail-fast at the `(m:EntityX {indexed_property: 1234})-[]->(a0)` part?

Comment: Can you show the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of your query?

Comment: I get this plan https://imgur.com/a/fQ70cqE for this query https://gist.github.com/maasha/d46d06944f9f3ef30a70f971430e9d6c

Comment: And another version https://imgur.com/a/rTaEY0I for query https://gist.github.com/maasha/65cd75d51436786e3513ddd3ab9935cc

Answer (score 0):

In your query you define a pattern, and the query planner try to find the best way starting point for your query.

Sadly, you haven't expand all the boxes on your profile, so I can't see what the query plan is doing.

But, to respond to your question, you can split your pattern by using the `WITH` in cypher.

So if you are sure that the first pattern make a good filter, then you can do something like that :

```
MATCH (m:EntityX {indexed_property: 1234})-->(a0:EntityY)
WITH m, ao
 MATCH (a0)--(a1:Entity:Y),
       (a1)--(a2:Entity:Y)
 ...
```

Cheers

Comment: Hm, it is still way faster to split the query into two separate ones, and only embark on the second if the first was a hit.